Тесты в django. Не создается задача через форму
Всем привет! помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с тестом. В test_post_task_create получаю код 200. И таска через форму не создается получается. Уже все испробовал, вроде все верно. Залогенный юзер автоматически становится автором таски при создании. На локале все работает как надо.
class Task_CRUD_test(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create(first_name='Al', last_name='Pacino', username='Scarface', password='123')
        self.client.force_login(self.user)
        self.status1 = Status.objects.create(name='готово')
        self.status2 = Status.objects.create(name='в процессе')
        self.task = Task.objects.create(name='The matrix', status=self.status1, author=self.user)


    def test_get_task_create(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('task:task_create'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'task/task_create.html')

    def test_post_task_create(self):
        form_data = TaskCreateForm(data={
            'name': 'Totoro',
            'description': 'must watch it!',
            'status': self.status2,
            }).data
        response = self.client.post(reverse('task_create'), form_data, follow=True)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        self.assertTrue(Task.objects.filter(name='Totoro').exists())
        task = Task.objects.get(name='Totoro')
        self.assertEqual(task.author_id, self.user.id)
        self.assertEqual(task.author.first_name, 'Al')
        self.assertRedirects(response, '/tasks/')
        self.assertEqual(task.status, 'в процессе')

 **А это сам вью.**

class TaskCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = Task
    form_class = TaskCreateForm
    template_name = 'task/task_create.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('tasks')
    success_message = 'Задача успешно создана'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super(TaskCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

**модель**
class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, verbose_name='Имя')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name= 'Описание')
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, related_name='status', on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Статус')
    executor = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='executor', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Исполнитель')
    labels = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Метки')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='author', on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Автор')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Task'

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Задача {self.name} от {self.author}. Cтатус {self.status}. Исполняет {self.executor}"



Если что-то должно создаваться, значит покажите код создания, наверное?

@andreymal вот view, но тут ничего необычного. Добавил еще само представление.

Тут нету кода создания, значит покажите форму наверное?

@andreymal в форме там просто поля перечислены class TaskCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Task
    fields = ['name', 'description', 'status', 'executor', 'labels']

На локал хосте все работает как надо, а вот тестах я где-то что-то упускаю(

Не вижу чтобы executor и labels были отмечены как опциональные, значит покажите модель наверное?

они да не обязательные. Добавил выше. спасибо!

Запустил тест у себя, первая ошибка: если вывести response.content, то там будет написано про неверное значение status, потому что вы зачем-то попытались отправить целый объект (что технически невозможно), а отправлять нужно вообще-то первичный ключ 'status': self.status2.id, — после этого исправления Task успешно создаётся

Вторая ошибка — вы указали follow=True, попросив клиента сходить по редиректам, а потом внезапно написали self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302) — разумеется, этот ассерт всегда будет ложным, ведь клиент уже сходил по всем редиректам вместо вас, так что конечно нужен follow=False

Третья ошибка: self.assertEqual(task.status, 'в процессе') — объект никогда не будет равен строке, нужно исправить строку в соответствии с тем, что вы на самом деле хотите проверить, например self.assertEqual(task.status.name, 'в процессе') или даже self.assertEqual(task.status.id, self.status2.id) — после этого тест у меня успешно проходит

Ну а проверка self.assertEqual(task.author.first_name, 'Al') скорее всего является избыточной, ведь вы уже проверили id

Да и кстати использование TaskCreateForm в тесте тоже является избыточным, form_data и переданный в форму словарь это один и тот же объект, так что можно сразу написать form_data = { ... } и не трогать форму попусту

@andreymal Cпасибо вам огромное! все сработало) Когда убрал TaskCreateForm и в качестве значений установил id, все отработало) Спасибо!
